# How to Fill FileUploader Default Value

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

I need a help to fill FileUpload Default file path using C# code

here is a file path `Server.MapPath("~/DemoTrack/DemoWorkout.mp4");`

which i want to fill in `FileUpload` by code of C# if the FileUpload value is null. in asp.net

please let me know how can I fill the FileUpload by code
I'm doing this

```
FileUploadDemoVideo.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/DemoTrack/DemoWorkout.mp4"));

FileUploadAudio.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/DemoTrack/DemoTrack.mp3"));
String DfileExtension = 

System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileUploadDemoVideo.FileName).ToLower();

String AudioExtension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileUploadAudio.FileName).ToLower();
```

i want to FileUploadDemoVideo and FileUploadAudio by code this is a file path Server.MapPath("~/DemoTrack/DemoWorkout.mp4") which i want to fill in FileUpload with a code wright in c# i just want to fill a FileUpload control then i can get a fileName and Extension so can convert in a Default value in `byte[]` and store that byte in sql data base if use didnt select the any file using FileUpload the Default value audio and video byte will be saved in database. as per that file which i fixed for audio and video.

I want to add a fix audio and video fill url in both audio and video FileUpload control with the code.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what you're trying to do. Please add more detail. Show us some code and what part you're having trouble with.

Comment: HI Jim i edit the distinction of my question more hope now you can understand..

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding, you want to save the default audio & video, if there is no input from the user. If this is the case, you can directly save the file onto database without involving your file-upload control. Filling the default file path on the file-upload control doesn't make any sense on client machine, since your default contents resides on server.

Comment: no i want to fill a FileUpload by code when i that  FileUploadDemoVideo and FileUploadAudio control by code when user never select any file in this 2 control then i want to save audio and video by in byte in SQL Server  which i fix a path of demo file of video and audio in my project.

Comment: In web applications, filling up a a default path on UI doesn't make any sense. If the user don't select anything, you can still pass the default files to database as `byte[]` via code. No need of filling your control with that path.